# getHours() and getUTCHours in Code by Zapier (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, utc, dst, zapier

In a Code by Zapier task, how to I get the local time of a date/time provided in UTC.  I am in time zone Europe/London. At the time of posting, owing to daylight saving, 9 AM London time is 8 AM UTC. But the following both return 8 when used in a Code by Zapier task.

```
var myDateTime = new Date("2020-09-01T08:00:00.000Z");
var localHours = myDateTime.getHours(); // returns 8
var utcHours = myDateTime.getUTCHours(); // returns 8
```

Answer (score 0):

What about below method? If date formate is always like that.

```
+'2020-09-01T09:00:00.000+01:00'.split('T')[1].slice(0,2); // 9
```

+ used to convert the result to number;

Comment: Thank you Ahmad.  You're right, that works if my variable is a string.  But my variable is a date/time.  I have edited my question to set this out better.

Answer (score 0):

Zapier code is run in AWS Lambda, where the local time is always UTC.

You can use the JS `toLocaleString` to convert to your local timezone.

```js
new Date().toLocaleString('en-GB', {timeZone: 'Europe/London'})
```

I wasn't able to get the locale working correctly locally in Node.js, but it does to the TZ correctly.

Lots of other options here: [Convert date to another timezone in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer to the question:

```
function getLocalDatetime(utcDatetime, timeZone) {
  const dt = new Date(utcDatetime).toLocaleString("en-US", { timeZone });
  return new Date(dt);
}

const myUTCDatetime = new Date("2020-09-01T08:00:00.000Z");
const myLocalDatetime = getLocalDatetime(myUTCDatetime, "Europe/London");
const utcHours = myUTCDatetime.getHours();
const localHours = myLocalDatetime.getHours();

return {
  myUTCDatetime: myUTCDatetime,
  myLocalDatetime: myLocalDatetime,
  utcHours: utcHours,
  localHours: localHours
};
```

See discussion here: https://community.zapier.com/ask-the-community-3/gethours-and-getutchours-in-code-by-zapier-javascript-4734?postid=17229#post17229